# Re render a CompositeView's itemview but not it's childViews

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a CompositeView with a collection.  The CompositeView has its own model and view that is pretty complex and changes made it to its childViews need to trigger the CompositeView's view to re render but not its childViews.  Is that possible?

I read in the Marionette docs "You can specify a modelView to use for the model. If you don't
specify one, it will default to the Marionette.ItemView."  But nothing happens when I try to use this in my CompositeView.

Answer (score 0):

Your CompositeView should listen for change event of own model and should call render on that. In this way the only ItemView associated with the composite view will re-rendered on change of own model not all childView.

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render)
```

You can put this line inside initialize method of CompositeView.